# Row operations on matrix

Tags: matrices

After applying several elementary transformations to matrix $$A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0\\ -3 & 2 & 0\\ 2 & -1 & 0\\ \end{array} \right)$$an equivalent matrix $$\left( \begin{array}{ccc} -3 & 2 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\4 & -3 & x\\ \end{array} \right) $$

was received. Find $x$. Try to solve this problem using the operations described in the lesson.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Could you format the formulæ using Mathjax? IWhat you problem iss not really understandable

Answer (score 1):

1.step $$R_3:-2R_2-R_3$$
2.step $$R_1 \longleftrightarrow R_2$$

So $$x=0$$

Answer (score 0):

If you apply elementary row operations to $A$, you can never get anything other than $0$ in the rightmost column. So $x=0$.